# How to send AJAX POST request and play the audio in the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, audio, html5-audio

I am building an app where the user can click a button, and it sends data to the server. The server then computes audio based on the data in the request (most likely a POST), and returns a WAV file to the browser.

I have already built the part with accepting a post request and responding with the wav file, but I can't figure out how to send the request in JS and to play the response to the user.

Also, the playing of the audio must start (almost) as the first byte comes in, as the audio files are quite large, and the user can't just wait for the request to be completed.

I am also open to suggestions changing how the server sends the file: the server is made in [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: did you see this link?
https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav/blob/master/demo/index.js

Comment: I don't think that is what I need - it doesn't play the audio, nor does it play/somehow return the audio in real-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <audio controls>
        <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
            data: { attr1: 'value1' },
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                $('audio #source').attr('src', data);
                $('audio').get(0).load();
                $('audio').get(0).play();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While the `get.php` just prints the audio file link. Note that I didn't get any WAV file so can't test on that.

```
<?php echo 'http://junaidahmed.io/w/audio.mp3'; ?>
```

That audio I'm printing above is a 30 minute and about 13mb file size. My internet is not fast enough to load the whole file in a second or two and yet it plays right away.

Comment: Thanks! One problem though: for speed, it's probably better for the server to return the audio directly, not return a URL for the audio, and have the browser have to make another request. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Audio file content could be easily returned but then you'll get that **large-file** issue because I think the HTTP request needs to be completed before doing anything, and secondly I don't know how to handle it back in the DOM.

Comment: If it's asyncronous, then the http request shouldn't block the page. Nevertheless, thanks, the performance doesn't matter that much.