# How can i read binary audio file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using an API for Text-To-Speech, the API is returning a binary file in response, now i need to know how can i read the binary file? I have run the same example in postman but somehow postman is converting the binary response to its actual form.
Here's the postman view, exactly what i want.
[image]

Now can i achieve this in javascript? Here's my api code.

```
var settings = {
    "url": "https://api.us-south.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/7f035f19-d994-4da1-90bf-4aa251df75fa/v1/synthesize?apikey=LPRALjC53IgE-QxB_gdNq4TjpIfXMWJRrWqKIgGhbMgJ&voice=en-US_EmilyV3Voice",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "audio/wav",
      "Authorization": "Basic YXBpa2V5OkxQUkFMakM1M0lnRS1ReEJfZ2ROcTRUanBJZlhNV0pScldxS0lnR2hiTWdK",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({"text":"attitude"}),
  };
  
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      //how can i convert the binary response here...
     
  });
```

Comment: Have you considered the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)? Or maybe the [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element, possibly with a [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)?

Comment: What do you think is the difference between "binary response" and "actual form," exactly? It's a binary format. I think maybe you are asking how to take the binary data and play it? Or what?

Comment: No, do you have any examples?

Comment: @John Wu, yes you're right i want to play same like what postman is doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send AJAX POST request and play the audio in the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896667/how-to-send-ajax-post-request-and-play-the-audio-in-the-response)

Comment: @John Wu No, as I'm receiving binary data and i guess in your mentioned example they're getting URL in return.

Comment: Wondering how postman is able to render the binary data.

Comment: what do you mean show the network tab of the request. postman probably adds missing headers like `content-type` from the server-response from api.

Comment: @john Smith what else you want to see from postman?

Comment: @Saif i want to see from your browser dev-tools the server.response (headers) of the ajax call

Comment: @johnSmith i hope this is what you're saying http://srecorder.com/s/9o21

Comment: @Saif the problem is probably that you are not using a webserver eg. you are working with file-protocoll and therefore fails 'mixed content' ;) The answer would be get a local webserver like apache running to work with http

Comment: @johnSmith now have install an httpServer using Node, and when upon receiving the binary response i create blob url which is created something like this blob:http://127.0.0.1:8080/ac00b87e-89b2-46e6-bb07-2b2c72e58e4a  - but its still not working i'm getting console error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Comment: @Saif you almost have it, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934862/how-to-replay-an-audio-blob-in-javascript